# 550 Unroute Address - Need Exim solution for all emails to come

Tags: php, email, exim

I am getting an error which says " The response from the remote server was: 550 Unrouteable address " .

My host of the email is valid and working good. But I need something like kjcnjkhb@abc.com.mydomain.com , when an email is sent to such an address it should come to my admin email.

I've enabled " catch all" so if I put any random email swejdnewkdn@mydomain.com , I get it my admin email.

But need an email when such kind of email is entered: dewdjkln@abcdne.com.mydomain.com ,

I believe there are some setting to be done in Exim maybe to solve this. I need all emails which has my host to come in my email.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the error you're describing, "500 Unroutable address", is being generated by the client, then the problem is that there is no DNS MX record for abc.com.mydomain.com.  The client doesn't know what server handles abc.com.mydomain.com. Your mail server isn't even being hit.

You may need to configure your DNS with a catchall MX record. Something like this:

```
*.mydomain.com.   3600 IN  MX 10 smtp.mydomain.com.
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Appreciate you response. Well I have already done that but I am still not getting the email. For some reason, when I use dig command to see where the MX is resolving the email address is showing "\" sign in between. For example I am sending an email to abc@abc.com.mydomain.com , In dig command I see abc\@abc.com.mydomain.com , NOT SURE what could be issue over here.

Comment: for testing, you can see my domain: joomlaupgradeservice.com so see all the enteries. Thanks again.

Comment: dig resolves domains, not email addresses.  `dig mx joomlaupgradeservice.com` returns "mail.joomlaupgradeservice.com" in the `ANSWER SECTION` while `dig mx abc.com.joomlaupgradeservice.com` does not resolve to anything (no answer section is returned)